# switch inside tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, switch-statement, return-value

i want to use switch function inside tabview cellForRowAtIndexPath to change the content of table

the scenario : the flag variable should select which the case and return it's content.

the error : i have to use return cell out side the switch function if i use it still give me error.

```
switch (flag){
    case 0 :

        let cell:mineCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mineCell")as! mineCell
        // User Name on cells
        cell.usernameLabel.text = creator[indexPath.row]

        //function

            else {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        return cell
        break

    case 1 :
        let cell:followingCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("followingCell")as! followingCell
        // User Name on cells
        cell.followingNameLabel.text = creator[indexPath.row]

    //ffuntion

            else {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        return cell

        break
    case 2 :

        //funtion 
        break
    default:
        break

    }



 //*HERE i have to use return cell but if i use it will give me error in somehow * 

}
```

Comment: in default, you need to return a UITableViewCell() I guess

Comment: where is the "`if`" part of  ` else {
                print(error)
            }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `cellForRow` method

```
switch (flag){

 case 0 :

        let cell:mineCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mineCell")as! mineCell
        // User Name on cells
        cell.usernameLabel.text = creator[indexPath.row]

        //function

            else {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        return cell
        break

    case 1 :
        let cell:followingCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("followingCell")as! followingCell
        // User Name on cells
        cell.followingNameLabel.text = creator[indexPath.row]

    //ffuntion

            else {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        return cell

        break
    }     
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has to return a `UITableViewCell` object or subclass of it in every possible scenario. Therefore you have to return a `UITableViewCell()` in your default case to get rid of your error.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to declare the `UITableViewCell` object in global.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        switch (flag) {
            case 0 :
            {
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mineCell")as! mineCell
                // User Name on cells
                cell.usernameLabel.text = creator[indexPath.row]
                //function
                if()
                {
                }else {
                    print(error)
                }
               return cell
            }

                break
            case 1 :
            {

            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("followingCell")as! followingCell
            // User Name on cells
            cell.followingNameLabel.text = creator[indexPath.row]

            //ffuntion
                if()
                {
                }
            else {
                print(error)
            }
           return cell
        }
        break
            default:
                break
        }


    return cell
    }
```